# Test Complete Automation - Issue with waiting for an object to load

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

**Background:**

I have a **JAVA** application on which we run our Test Complete scripts(We have recently moved from UFT to TestComplete, so TC is a bit new for us). The scripting language used is **VBScript**.

**Issue:**

In order to handle the slow application behavior, I have created a function which waits for an object to get loaded and become visible on the screen before any operation is performed on that object. But, at times, the function does not work. By this, I mean that even though the object is loaded and is visible on the screen, the function still keeps on waiting for the object i.e., `uiObject.exists` keeps on returning `false` due to which it keeps on waiting until the timeout value is reached. Has someone here faced this issue before?

**Paramter values passed:**

```
uiObject = Aliases.ParentObj.Login_Window
intMaxTimeOut = 120
```

**Code**

```
'============================================================================================================
'Function Name: fn_waitForObject
'Purpose:       To wait for an object to exist and become visible on screen
'Creation Date: 04-06-2018 
'Return type:   true, if the object exists and is visible; false, if the object doesn't exist
'Parameters:    uiObject - The object for which the script waits to get visible on screen
'               intMaxTimeOut - Maximum timeout in seconds
'============================================================================================================
function fn_waitForObject(uiObject,intMaxTimeOut)
    Dim intCounter : intCounter = 0
    Do While (intCounter < intMaxTimeOut)
        If uiObject.exists then
            Exit Do
        Else
            intCounter = intCounter + 1
            delay 1000
        End If
    Loop
    
    'If the object exists, make sure that it is visible on screen
    If uiObject.exists then
        Do While (intCounter < intMaxTimeOut)
            If uiObject.visibleonscreen then
                Log.Message "The object """&uiObject.toString&""" exists and is visible on screen"
                Exit Do
            Else
                intCounter = intCounter + 1
                delay 1000
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    fn_waitForObject = uiObject.visibleonscreen
End Function
```

**Object Spy**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the information on this link can help you!

> [whats is the difference between UIObject and UIObject2 other than UIAutomator 2.0 version name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881680/whats-is-the-difference-between-uiobject-and-uiobject2-other-than-uiautomator-2)

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual error saying in TC?

Have you seen this link? https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/common-tasks/waiting-process-or-window-activation.html

I would also suggest trying to use the record keyword test, then convert it to script

For now you could increase your max timeout value, but your while loop will still have a hard upper limit.  I recommend using one of the methods listed in the article above, as they will make TestComplete wait until your process/objects have fully loaded, no matter how much time has passed.  That way, you won't run into your current problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Name Mapping creating a 2nd version of the same object.

Go into the Name Mapping and edit the properties to only use static properties, so new versions of the same UIObject are not being created.